# convert multiple columns to datetime without the date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, one for hour, one for minute, and one for second, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': [9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 10.0],
                   'min': [12.0, 13.0, 55.0, 2.0],
                   'sec': [42.0, 30.0, 12.0, 5.0]})

>>> df
   hour   min   sec
0   9.0  12.0  42.0
1   9.0  13.0  30.0
2   9.0  55.0  12.0
3  10.0   2.0   5.0
```

I'm trying to combine the three columns into a new column made up of a datetime series. The goal would be to have this dataframe:

```
   hour   min   sec      time
0   9.0  12.0  42.0   9:12:42
1   9.0  13.0  30.0   9:13:30
2   9.0  55.0  12.0   9:55:12
3  10.0   2.0   5.0  10:02:05
```

So far I'm trying to use `pd.to_datetime`, as such:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['hour', 'min', 'sec']],
                        format = '%H:%M:S')
```

But I'm getting the following ValueError:
`ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`.

I was trying to avoid this by including the `format` argument with only hour minute second, but apparently that doesn't work.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375471/pandas-convert-strings-to-time-without-date), but the solutions proposed do not seem to work in this case, I'm still getting this ValueError

Any ideas to solve this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

[EDIT]: I also needed the method to be able to deal with NaNs, so a dataframe such as this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': [9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 10.0, np.nan],
                   'min': [12.0, 13.0, 55.0, 2.0, np.nan],
                   'sec': [42.0, 30.0, 12.0, 5.0, np.nan]})
```

The solution proposed by @PiRSquared works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pd.to_datetime` on a dataframe with the requisite column names to create a series of datetimes.

However, OPs initial dataframe has a `'min'` column that needs to be renamed `'minute'` and a `'sec'` column that needs to be renamed '`second`'.

In addition, I'll add the missing columns `'year'`, `'month'`, and `'day'` using `pd.DataFrame.assign`.

Finally, I'll add the `'time'` column with `pd.DataFrame.assign` again.

```
new = dict(year=2017, month=1, day=1)
rnm = dict(min='minute', sec='second')
df.assign(
    time=pd.to_datetime(
        df.rename(columns=rnm).assign(**new)
    ).dt.time
)

   hour   min   sec      time
0   9.0  12.0  42.0  09:12:42
1   9.0  13.0  30.0  09:13:30
2   9.0  55.0  12.0  09:55:12
3  10.0   2.0   5.0  10:02:05
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared ! This works, and deals fine with NaNs (which I have in my actual dataframe).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there is a more direct way but this works

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'].astype(int).astype(str)+':'+df['min'].astype(int).astype(str)+':'+df['sec'].astype(int).astype(str), format = '%H:%M:%S').dt.time


    hour    min     sec     time
0   9.0     12.0    42.0    09:12:42
1   9.0     13.0    30.0    09:13:30
2   9.0     55.0    12.0    09:55:12
3   10.0    2.0     5.0     10:02:05
```

Comment: Thanks @Vaishali, Yeah, I was trying something similar, but your way works for this example. Seems like there must be a more efficient way without converting to int and back to string. The issue with this is if my full dataframe has NaNs (which it does), it can't be converted to int. But I suppose I could just get rid of them if needed

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df.apply(lambda x: ":".join([str(int(v)) for v in x]), axis=1), format="%H:%M:%S").dt.time  <- how about this?

Comment: @Tai, I wouldn't use apply for something that can be done using vectorized operations

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks for the comments! Appreciate it.