# Converting Pandas Object to minutes and seconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in for stop_time `05:38` (MM:SS) but it is showing up as an object. is there a way to turn this to a time?

I tried using `# perf_dfExtended['Stop_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(perf_dfExtended['Stop_Time'], format='%M:%S')`

but then it adds a date to the output: `1900-01-01 00:05:38`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - convert strings to time without date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375471/pandas-convert-strings-to-time-without-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is *pd.to_timedelta* (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html). *to_datetime* operation which will of course always try to create a date.

What you have to remember about though is that pd.to_timedelta could raise ValueError for your column, as it requires hh:mm:ss format. Try to use apply function on your column by adding '00:' by the beginning of arguments of your column (which I think are strings?), and then turn the column to timedelta. Could be something like:

```
pd.to_timedelta(perf_dfExtended['Stop_Time'].apply(lambda x: f'00:{x}'))
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you. Is there a way to clip the results though so it doesnt show days and hours? my data will never go past minutes

Comment: Not according to my knowledge, sorry. Maybe you can have one column to perform analysis and calculations, and another for showing the data (original column)?

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
perf_dfExtended['Stop_Time'] = \
    pd.to_datetime(perf_dfExtended['Stop_Time'], format='%M:%S').dt.time
```

**Output** (with some additional examples)

```
0    00:05:38
1    00:10:17
2    00:23:45
```

Comment: This works however the column is still dtype: object. I cannot apply calculations to it.