# pandas - retain timestamp format only for time (not date)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xml, timestamp

I am using the benedict python library to parse a `.xml` file (sample below):

```
data_source = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunInfo Version="5">
   <Run Id="210910_A00154_0856_BH2TTNDMXY" Number="856">
        <Date>9/10/2021 3:08:02 PM</Date>
   </Run>
</RunInfo>"""
```

Eventually what I want to parse is the time in the format of timestamp, but without the date i.e. only `3:08:02 PM`

Given that

`type(data['RunInfo']['Run']['Date'])` results in `str`

I did `pd.to_datetime(data['RunInfo']['Run']['Date'])`

yet the date is there for obvious reasons.

So I though about slicing only the part I want to parse (`3:08:02 PM`), then I would convert it to timeStamp format, with `pd.to_datetime(data['RunInfo']['Run']['Date'][-10:], format="%H:%M:%S")`

But what happened is that `pd.to_dateTime()` still outputs a date, now a random one, which is worse.

Does anyone know how can I parse only the time from the original `.xml` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375471/pandas-convert-strings-to-time-without-date

Answer (score 1):

We can convert this `9/10/2021 3:08:02 PM` in `DataTime` format like so :

```py
>>> df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

Then, to extract the time :

```py
>>> df['timestamp'].dt.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: pd.to_datetime should infer the format correctly, no need to specify it explicitly I think

Comment: Indeed, I just remove the format it works perfectly, I updated the answer to simplify it. Thanks @MrFuppes !